# Remove undefined from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I need to remove empty (undefined) items from the multidimensional array. Atm my code looks like this (it's a method I run so that's why i am using `this`:

```
f: function(arr) {
    var __ = this;
    arr = arr.filter(function(item) {
        return Array.isArray(item) ? __.f(item) : typeof(item) !== "undefined";
    });
return arr;
}
```

but if i run `console.log(myObject.f([1, 2, , , , , 3, 4, [5, , , , , ], 6, , , , 8, 3, [[[], 9]]]));`
i get `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, [ 5, , , ,  ], 6, 8, 3, [ [ [], 9 ] ] ]` and that is kinda weird result. I goes pretty well for the first layer but removes only one undefined from inner layers. Also I would like to remove a subarray that consists of no items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reductions people! They are beautiful!

```
function stripUndefined (arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (result, item) {
    result.push( Array.isArray(item) && !item.length ? stripUndefined(item) : item );
    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Very elegant, thanks! So I take it `reduce` skips `undefined` items entirely and that's why it does not throw a syntax error regarding length check of `undefined`

Comment: Correct. Strictly speaking Gilad's answer is also a reduction - the process of accumulating some result while looping over a collection - but Array.prototype.reduce does happen to exclude "holes" in the array

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but here `result` is a collector that all the items of an array are reduced into, and `item` is the next iteration of an item queue of an original array. What grabbed my attention is the idea that `reduce` goes down the array to reduce it, item by item. But why does not ternary throw an error when it reaches `undefined` item as you can not check the length of `undefined`?

Comment: "reduce executes the callback function once for each element present in the array, excluding holes in the array"

Comment: "excluding holes in the array" 
now I got it.
Tho this *edi*t: `Array.isArray(item) && !item.length` makes no sense for me.

Comment: I added that after noticing that `undefined` values are skipped but `null` is not. Also because strings have a length.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, , , , , 3, 4, [5, , , , , ], 6, , , , 8, 3, [[[], 9]]];

var remove = function (array) {
  var result = [];

  array.forEach(function (item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item) && item.length!=0) {
      // Item is a nested array, go one level deeper recursively
      result.push(remove(item));
    }
    else if (typeof item !== 'undefined') {
      result.push(item);
    }
  });

  return result;
};
```

And then `console.log(remove(arr));` gives us `[1, 2, 3, 4, [5], 6, 8, 3, [[[], 9]]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, simple but smart! Also I wonder, is there a technical possibility to *cut out* that null-length array `[]` (the deeper nested one)?

Comment: @AlexBykov See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Gilad's answer, but completely skipping arrays that result in an empty array (eg `[,,,,,]`)

```
function cleanArray2d(array){
  var result = [];

  array.forEach(function (item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item) && item.length!=0) {
      // Item is a nested array, go one level deeper recursively

      var nestedArray = cleanArray2d(item);
      if (nestedArray.length > 0)
        result.push(cleanArray2d(item));
    }
    else if (typeof item !== 'undefined' && item != "") {
      result.push(item);
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```